# aws cloudformation -resource property error

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have defined my parameters like this:

```
{
    "PrivateSubnets":{
       "Description":"db subnetlist",
       "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    },

    "VPCLIST": {
       "Description": "VPC list",
       "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>"
    }
}
```

and referring the above parameters in "resources" section like below:

```
    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref": "VPCLIST"} ,
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable 3306/80/SSH access via port 22"
}
```

and while executing this I am getting the below error.

AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup InstanceSecurityGroup   "Value of property VpcId must be of type String"

Note: I have only default VPC available which is not taken as string? any solutions to this issue...

Comment: Below is the error message : Error
Unable to list data: Internal Failure

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is make this change:

```
{
  "PrivateSubnets": {
    "Description":"db subnetlist",
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
  },
  "VPCLIST": {
    "Description": "VPC list",
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Security Groups requires the VpcId to be a string, the property is an array list, So you need to change the property to Type: String, or use the 
[Fn::Select](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) function.

```
{ "Fn::Select" : [ 0, VPCLIST ] }
```

List – **An array of VPC IDs**

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
     "GroupName" : String,
     "GroupDescription" : String,
     "SecurityGroupEgress" : [ Security Group Rule, ... ],
     "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ Security Group Rule, ... ],
     "Tags" :  [ Resource Tag, ... ],
     "VpcId" : String
  }
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html